# How android shows wifi login page for some wifi connections and opens it in browser automatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi

I wanted to know if we can programatically make the wifi login page open in browser on attempting to connect to a specific wifi connection.
For example: I have wifi hotspot 'A' and when I am trying to connect to this hotspot from my android Phone 'B', then it should open a page in browser for login( As it happens for the wifi in hotels). Anyone has any idea how it works?

Answer (score 0):

That is not related to your phone or android or device or OS !!!!
its a network setting which can be set up via the router setting

But you can do tings like getting wifi statue and if the mac address or id or name was your desired one, you make an intent and redirect user to your desired page in broswer.

Comment: :Thanks. Ok so I will have to do nothing on android side? Once the setting is done at network side, then it will automatically launch my browser with the url on connection to the wifi

Comment: Yes, but my intention is that this 'launching of url in browser on connection' should happen with the app not being installed on the phone.

Comment: i got it. yes , just setup the router and any device connected to that hot spot would be redirected to your desired url